# Selected data from non-contiguous cells ordering different with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I create a graph manually, select a range of days comprising an entire month, then ctrl+click a single cell containing the month to date sum.

When I create the graph manually, select the days first, then the MTD cell, it displays correctly (see two columns way off to the right).

I copied the way it stored the data source and set that using VBA but now the MTD value keeps moving to the first bar in the chart rather than at the end like the manual chart does.

The data source of the graph that looks correct is

```
=(Dashboard!$G$110:$AK$110,Dashboard!$F$110)
```

What I put in the VBA code as data source is:

```
Set rng = ws.Range("$G$110:$AK$110,$F$110")
```

So the `F110` cell gets moved to the front in VBA.

The labels are selected the same and they work.

Comment: Actually... You can post pics. Just click the picture button.

Comment: @K.Davis sorry for the confusion, you're right. I was mistaken.

Comment: I tried to add pics but is said I have to have a higher reputation rank or something like that.

I worked around it by just copying via formula the total field into a hidden cell at the end of the data range so it is placed in order on the graph. 

I still would like to know why it rearranges the data differently if I assign the data range through the user interface and via VBA code.